# Cisco enable username and enable password equivalent in HP

Tags: cisco, hp

If Cisco has a enable username and enable password what is the equivalent term use by HP?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since i do not know what type of HP switch you have, the general command to use, as you describe is:

```
Switch(config)# password manager user-name admin
```

When pressing enter, you will be prompted to enter password:

```
New password: ******** 
Please retype new password: ******* 
Switch(config)# write mem
```

That should be it. The command might change on newer equipment, but i'm not sure.

Comment: You should note that the `user-name` option actually sets an alias to that user account. `manager` can still be used.